# Possible to coalesce patch edits to one file?

Tags: unix, patch, bitkeeper

I'm using [bitkeeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitKeeper) which can generate patches from a series of committed changes based on certain parameters.

e.g.

```
bk changes -vvL
```

Will generate a patch-file for all the edits which are in my repo, but not in my parent repo.

Unfortunately, if I edit and commit a file 3 times and then the patch will have 3 different edits in the patch.

Is there a way that I can merge all these edits to the same file into one edit section in the patch?

Assume the format is a simple patch, or that I can coerce the patch to look like a simple patch created using `diff -u`.  I also don't want to manually generate the patch by doing a `diff -R -u` since our repository is multiple gigabytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with bitkeeper; but, if there is no better option, you may be able to do what you want using `combinediff` from [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) (plus a bit of scripting).